# Limit administrator RDP session to single instance instead of default 2 simultaneous?

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, rdp, connlimit

I have a special request case on one server, win2003 R2, where they are accessing it via RDP administrative session.  There are multiple users who access it but they want to ensure only a single user is capable of being logged in at any given moment.  I would like to change the default number of allowed simultaneous admin connections permitted from default of 2 to 1.

I have other options in mind, but they would involve only allowing a unique username to log in and not letting the users use their own administrative accounts for RDP.  I'm curious if I can actually alter the OS default simultaneous limit though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Terminal Services Configuration -> Connections -> RDP-Tcp -> (right-click) Properties -> Network Adapter?

There's an option “Maximum connections” that may be what you’re looking for.

Comment: Indeed.  Well answered, Dave.  Well hidden, MS!